# two cross product group with no data link in oracle matrix report

Tags: oracle10g

I have 2 cross product groups in my matrix report. I then place a formula column in my master group. Then I want to use this formula column in the other master group, but it gives me an error that both formulas must belong to same cross product group columns (have incompatible frequency).

Both of these cross product groups are not linked with data link.

Comment: Your question would benefit from more precise phrasing, i.e. what did you do *exactly* (providing scripts or screenshots) and stating the *exact* error message and how you *actually* provoked the error. In addition, the more frequent use of punctuation marks including respective use of casing might render your OP visually more appealing to potential readers.

Comment: REP-1517:column CF_5  references column CF_3,which has incompatible frequency, when i add both column formula values belong to different cross product group in matrix report.then above error display...

Comment: function CF_3Formula return Number is
       total_t_score varchar2(50);
begin
      total_t_score:=(ROUND((:CS_2/(:CS_5*5))*100)*0.6);
       RETURN( total_t_score);
end;

Comment: i m forming a master/master report